# Why can't I see .Net 4.6 option for API Compatibility Level?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity. I want to use the latest version of .Net. It seems as though the .Net version has only very recently been upgraded to .Net 4.6 as described in this blog post: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/upgraded-mono-net-in-editor-on-5-5-0b4.433541/. I do not see .Net 4.6 in the API compatibility level setting described in the blog post. I have tried this with Unity 5.5.2f1 and Unity 5.6.0b9. What might I be missing?

Comment: (This question was also asked on the Unity forum: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1319508/why-cant-i-see-net-46-option-for-api-compatibility.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to use the latest version of .Net.

You **can't** with the official Unity version.

> It seems as though the .Net version has only very recently been
>   upgraded to .Net 4.6 as described in this blog post:

That is a *special* version of Unity that is only used for experimental purposes. That is not meant to be used to ship your finished game.

.Net 4.6 is not officially supported yet. It's been worked on and will likely be supported by the end of this year.

You can use the unofficial/experimental version *5.6.0b5* from this [link](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/upgraded-mono-net-in-editor-and-some-players-on-5-6-0b5.454387/). It will let you use *.Net 4.6*  on the Editor. It will not work on builds because the run-time for other platforms are not yet finished.

If you download this, you are helping Unity improve their *.Net 4.6*. Don't download it because you want to release your game with APIs' from *.Net 4.6.*

**EDIT**:

For the latest experimental release, Windows, OSX, Linux standalone
iOS with IL2CPP Android with IL2CPP and Mono are now supported.

Although, there are still bugs to fix, and many platforms are not yet supported. That's why you should not release your game with this.

**EDIT 2**:

[**Unity 2017.1.0b1**](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta) is now released and it supports *.NET 4.6*. It is still in beta mode.

Go to *Edit* --> *Project Settings* --> *Player* --> *Other Settings* --> *Configuration* --> *Scripting Runtime Version* --> *.NET 4.6 Equivalent*

then

Go to *Edit* --> *Project Settings* --> *Player* --> *Other Settings* --> *Configuration* --> *Api Compatibility Level* --> *.NET 4.6*

Comment: That explains the relative silence on the topic.

Comment: Yup but Unity is almost there. Very soon, we will be able to use *.NET 4.6*. Probably in Unity 6 since it will be out in couple of months.

Comment: [Here](http://www.gamesindustry.biz/articles/2016-12-14-unity-dropping-major-updates-in-favour-of-date-based-model) is a post describing the subscription service with a line stating "Unity 2017 is scheduled to go into beta in April"