# .NET 4.6 don't fully support in Unity?

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, version-compatibility

I changed .NET version in my project to 4.6, but I still cannot use [GeoCoordinate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate(v=vs.110).aspx) class. 
Haven't I done something wrong or Unity don't fully support .NET 4.6?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I see .Net 4.6 option for API Compatibility Level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513782/why-cant-i-see-net-4-6-option-for-api-compatibility-level)

Answer (score 3):

Unity supports possibly all the C# 6 features. It does **not** support all *.NET 4.6 API* because it uses Mono. Even with .NET 3.5, there are also many other API that Unity did not support because Mono did not support it.

This should **not** be a problem at-all. You can get the GeoCoordinate API replica from [github](https://github.com/ghuntley/geocoordinate). All you need are the [`GeoCoordinate.cs`](https://github.com/ghuntley/geocoordinate/blob/master/src/GeoCoordinatePortable/GeoCoordinate.cs) and the [`GeoPosition.cs`](https://github.com/ghuntley/geocoordinate/blob/master/src/GeoCoordinatePortable/GeoPosition.cs) files.

The function names and everything else is interchangeable with Microsoft's `System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate`.

Sample Usage when imported into Unity and after [initializing](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LocationService.Start.html)GPS (if using with Unity's GPS API):

```
LocationInfo gpsInfo = Input.location.lastData;
LocationInfo gpsInfo2 = Input.location.lastData;


GeoCoordinate pin1 = new GeoCoordinate(gpsInfo.latitude, gpsInfo.longitude);
GeoCoordinate pin2 = new GeoCoordinate(gpsInfo2.latitude, gpsInfo2.longitude);

double distanceBetween = pin1.GetDistanceTo(pin2);
```

Answer (score 0):

"IL2CPP **fully supports** the new .NET 4.6 APIs, so you still get the benefits of writing in C# and the performance of native C++. If you find any issues, please jump over to the forum. "

https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/07/11/introducing-unity-2017/

This is experimental features, I don't think a lot of people are using it yet, so you'll probably have more answers on the dedicated forum :

https://forum.unity3d.com/forums/experimental-scripting-previews.107/